# GLFW Mouse drift

Tags: c++, mouse, glfw

I am currently developing a test project for OpenGL to discover its possibilities.
I am experiencing a weird bug with GLFW 4.0 apparently called "mouse drift" (from different github issues). It means that even though my mouse is not moving, the glfw input callback will still be called with small x and y values (generally 1 or -1).

I provided my code here : https://github.com/Lygaen/testgl (not ads or promoting, just giving the link to the full project to help reproduce). I am using a basic GLFW, GLAD and GLM framework.

My goal is to calculate the delta position of the mouse, to have correct camera movement.
Thank you for any help that you could provide !

Here is the code that calculates input :

window.h

```cpp
#ifndef __WINDOW_H__
#define __WINDOW_H__

#include <string>
#include <glad/gl.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <vector>

class Window
{
private:
    GLFWwindow *window;
    bool correctlyLoaded;
    static void resizeCallback(GLFWwindow *, int, int);

public:
    Window(const std::string &, int, int);
    ~Window();

    const bool hasCorrectlyLoaded();
    const bool shouldClose();

    const void pollEvents();
    const void exitNextFrame();
};

class Input
{
private:
    static char *keyStates;
    static bool *mouseStates;
    static glm::dvec2 pos;
    static glm::dvec2 delta;
    static std::vector<int> pressed;

    static void keyCallback(GLFWwindow *, int, int, int, int);
    static void mouseCallback(GLFWwindow *, double, double);
    static void mouseButtonCallback(GLFWwindow *, int, int, int);

public:
    static const bool isPressed(int);
    static const bool isDown(int);
    static const bool isReleased(int);
    static const glm::dvec2 getMousePosition();
    static const glm::dvec2 getMouseDelta();
    static const bool isMouseButtonDown(int);
    static const void setCallbacks(GLFWwindow *);
    static const void loopClear();
    static const void terminate();
};

#endif // __WINDOW_H__
```

window.cpp

```cpp
#include "window.h"
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>
#include <algorithm>

Window::Window(const std::string &title, int width, int height)
{
    correctlyLoaded = false;
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        spdlog::default_logger()->critical("Could not load GLFW");
        return;
    }

    spdlog::default_logger()->info("Loaded GLFW {}", glfwGetVersionString());

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!window)
    {
        spdlog::default_logger()->critical("Failed to create GLFW window !");
        return;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (!gladLoadGL(glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        spdlog::default_logger()->critical("Failed to load OpenGL !");
        return;
    }

    spdlog::default_logger()->info("Loaded OpenGL {}", glfwGetVersionString());

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);

    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, Window::resizeCallback);
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    Input::setCallbacks(window);

    correctlyLoaded = true;
}

Window::~Window()
{
    glfwTerminate();
}

void Window::resizeCallback(GLFWwindow *, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

const bool Window::hasCorrectlyLoaded()
{
    return correctlyLoaded;
}

const bool Window::shouldClose()
{
    return glfwWindowShouldClose(window);
}

const void Window::pollEvents()
{
    Input::loopClear();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}

const void Window::exitNextFrame()
{
    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

char *Input::keyStates;
bool *Input::mouseStates;
glm::tvec2<double> Input::pos;
glm::tvec2<double> Input::delta;
std::vector<int> Input::pressed;

void Input::keyCallback(GLFWwindow *, int key, int /*scancode*/, int action, int /*mods*/)
{
    if (key < 0 || key > GLFW_KEY_LAST)
        return;

    keyStates[key] = action;
    if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        pressed.push_back(key);
    }
}

void Input::mouseCallback(GLFWwindow *window, double nXPos, double nYPos)
{
    glm::dvec2 newPos = {nXPos, nYPos};
    delta = newPos - pos;
    pos = newPos;
    glfwSetCursorPos(window, 0, 0);
}

void Input::mouseButtonCallback(GLFWwindow *window, int button, int action, int /*mods*/)
{
    if (button < 0 || button > GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LAST)
        return;

    mouseStates[button] = action;
}

const bool Input::isPressed(int key)
{
    return std::count(pressed.begin(), pressed.end(), key);
}

const bool Input::isDown(int key)
{
    return keyStates[key] != GLFW_RELEASE;
}

const bool Input::isReleased(int key)
{
    return keyStates[key] == GLFW_RELEASE;
}

const glm::dvec2 Input::getMousePosition()
{
    return pos;
}

const glm::dvec2 Input::getMouseDelta()
{
    return delta;
}

const bool Input::isMouseButtonDown(int mouseButton)
{
    return mouseStates[mouseButton] == GLFW_PRESS;
}

const void Input::setCallbacks(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    keyStates = new char[GLFW_KEY_LAST];
    mouseStates = new bool[GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LAST];
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, Input::keyCallback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, Input::mouseCallback);
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, Input::mouseButtonCallback);
}

const void Input::loopClear()
{
    pressed.clear();
}

const void Input::terminate()
{
    delete[] keyStates;
    delete[] mouseStates;
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "gui/window.h"
#include "gui/gl/shader.h"
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>
#include <spdlog/fmt/bin_to_hex.h>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/scalar_multiplication.hpp>

glm::mat4 fpsView(glm::vec3 cam, float pitch, float yaw)
{
    float cosPitch = cos(pitch);
    float sinPitch = sin(pitch);
    float cosYaw = cos(yaw);
    float sinYaw = sin(yaw);

    glm::vec3 xaxis = {cosYaw, 0, -sinYaw};
    glm::vec3 yaxis = {sinYaw * sinPitch, cosPitch, cosYaw * sinPitch};
    glm::vec3 zaxis = {sinYaw * cosPitch, -sinPitch, cosPitch * cosYaw};

    // Create a 4x4 view matrix from the right, up, forward and eye position vectors
    glm::mat4 viewMatrix = {
        glm::vec4(xaxis.x, yaxis.x, zaxis.x, 0),
        glm::vec4(xaxis.y, yaxis.y, zaxis.y, 0),
        glm::vec4(xaxis.z, yaxis.z, zaxis.z, 0),
        glm::vec4(-glm::dot(xaxis, cam), -glm::dot(yaxis, cam), -glm::dot(zaxis, cam), 1)};

    return viewMatrix;
}

int main(int, char **)
{
#ifndef NDEBUG
    spdlog::set_level(spdlog::level::trace);
#endif

    Window window("Test GL", 800, 600);

    if (!window.hasCorrectlyLoaded())
    {
        return 1;
    }

    float vertices[] = {
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,   // top right
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // bottom right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // bottom left
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f   // top left
    };
    unsigned int indices[] = {
        // note that we start from 0!
        0, 1, 3, // first triangle
        1, 2, 3  // second triangle
    };

    Shader shader;

    unsigned int VAO;
    GL(glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO));
    GL(glBindVertexArray(VAO));

    unsigned int VBO;
    GL(glGenBuffers(1, &VBO));
    GL(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO));
    GL(glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW));

    unsigned int EBO;
    GL(glGenBuffers(1, &EBO));
    GL(glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO));
    GL(glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW));

    GL(glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 3, (void *)0));
    GL(glEnableVertexAttribArray(0));

    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(90.0f), (float)800 / (float)600, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    glm::vec3 cam{4, 3, 3};
    glm::vec2 dir{0, 0};

    glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);

    while (!window.shouldClose())
    {
        GL(glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f));
        GL(glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT));

        glm::mat4 View = fpsView(cam, dir.y, dir.x);
        glm::mat4 mvp = Projection * View * Model;
        shader.setUniform("MVP", &mvp);

        shader.bind();

        GL(glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO));
        GL(glBindVertexArray(VAO));
        GL(glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0));
        GL(glBindVertexArray(0));

        window.pollEvents();

        if (Input::isPressed(GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE))
        {
            window.exitNextFrame();
        }

        if (Input::isPressed(GLFW_KEY_F6))
        {
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
        }
        else if (Input::isReleased(GLFW_KEY_F6))
        {
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
        }

        glm::dvec2 d = Input::getMouseDelta();

        dir += d * 0.001;
    }

    spdlog::default_logger()->info("Quitting !");
}
```

Comment: Did you tryed to avoid call to `glfwSetCursorPos(window, 0, 0);` (with proper implementation to properly compute delta) to see if there is a difference ?

Comment: Already did, you can see it at the bottom of the `Input::mouseCallback` function containing delta calculations as well.

Comment: I can say that it calls the function even though the mouse has not been moved (tried by shutting off input with linux commands)

Comment: What I see at bottom of `Input::mouseCallback` is that you actually call `glfwSetCursorPos`... that is why I ask, but if you tell you tryed without... You say `Input::mouseCallback` function is called even if you unplug your mouse ?

Comment: Important precision, you are under Linux, which mean glfw probably rely on Xinput... and, I have some memory of such problem with Xinput, because of a bad interpretation of raw data. But this was long time ago now...

Comment: I can confirm that GLFW still calls the callback even if I unplug my mouse or virtually unplug my mousepad.
And what's the deal with XInput ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no clear memory, but the problem was about parsing and interpreting mouse raw input values as delivered by X server (which are relative motion delta values, natively). But in your case, you are receiving the cursor position, which is actually different process, even if glfw appear to call the callback on X event basis... If you print the values received by `Input::mouseCallback` with unplugged mouse and without calling `glfwSetCursorPos`, does the received cursor position really change on its own ?

Comment: It seems that without the `glfwSetCursorPos` it doesn't call the mouse callback

Comment: ok ! so this leads me to my first theory: I think that by calling glfwSetCursorPos within the callback, you produce a new mouse move event each time cursor change its position that call the callback again and so on recursively. This ends producing kind of Larsen effect with "noised" result.